# Artifactory user update removes admin

Tags: artifactory

Consider the following POST to the Artifactory REST API:

```
curl -f -u admin:password \
     -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
     -d '{ "groups": ["oldgroup", "newgroup"] }' \ 
     http://localhost/artifactory/api/security/users/targetuser
```

This request does ensure that the user is a member of both the "oldgroup" and the "newgroup" but additionally it removes admin privileges from the user (if they had it): Ex. `{ "admin": true }` changes to `{ "admin": false }` after the update.

It would appear that one would need to additionally pass `{ "admin": true }` if the user was an admin originally in order to avoid this strange side effect of the update:

```
curl -f -u admin:password \
     -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
     -d '{ "admin": true, "groups": ["oldgroup", "newgroup"] }' \ 
     http://localhost/artifactory/api/security/users/targetuser
```

This does not seem to be implemented as a true update. Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Additionally, I was wondering if this had to do with the `'Content-Type'` header I was originally passing as I was using the full `application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.security.User+json` but a change to just `application/json` has the same result.

I could see if I was using the PUT method to Create or Replace a user but this is the POST request and doesn't seem to be working as I expect it to.

---

Artifactory REST API Documentation and my research:

- Method: [Update User](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-UpdateUser)
- Object: [application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.security.User+json](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Security+Configuration+JSON)
- Similar unanswered post from the old Jfrog forums: [thread](http://forums.jfrog.org/updating-admin-password-removes-admin-rights-td7578741.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Artifactory, upon getting the update REST API command, can't tell which params you intended to change, for example in your case change the groups, it will take your input and apply it to the user. That means that the value of Admin will be set to false as this is the default value to that field. In case that you wish to save the existing configuration for the user, I would suggest doing a get request for the user details > saving it to a JSON file > edit it to the desired values > post it to Artifactory. That way you won't change the values that you intend to keep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had originally thought the same. However, if you take a look at the documentation for the RST API you'll notice their are two routes for updating User objects: `PUT` and `POST`. 

  - Create or Replace User: `PUT /api/security/users/{userName}`
  - Update User: `POST /api/security/users/{userName}`

The notes for the create or replace clearly state: "Missing values will be set to the default values"

However, for update: "Updates an exiting user in Artifactory with the provided user details"

Therefore, I do believe the update is working incorrectly.

Comment: Indeed, I can see that it seems that the documentation is missing this information for the "Update User" as well. This is indeed confusing, will ask to change it and to add this line to the "Update User" as well. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Live update, the documentation was updated accordingly.

Comment: I just noticed the update to the documentation; thank you, at the very least this clarifies the confusion from a documentation perspective. It still begs the question of the necessity of the POST route and it's difference from the PUT route as they are almost identical (with the exception of the POST - I'm assuming - requiring the referenced user already exist). I also meant to add previously that I am essentially doing what you suggested in my application but the necessity to do so threw me off initially.